# Computing an Integral Involving Rational and Bessel Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, bessel-functions

I tried to compute the following integral by using Contour integration method.
$$
    \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}J_0(ax) dx
$$
where $J_0$ is Bessel function of the first kind and $a$ is a positive real constant. Based on the [table of integrals](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) (p. 672), we expect to have $-\operatorname{kei}(a)$ as the answer, where $\operatorname{kei}$ is [Kelvin function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kei.html). I wanted to compute it myself but I ended up with a different answer. Here is what I did:
The poles on upper half-plan are $\sqrt{i}$ and $i\sqrt{i}$. Because $\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}J_0(ax)$ is an even function, by using residue theorem I simply expect that
$$
    \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}J_0(ax) dx =\frac{2\pi i}{2}\Big(\frac{J_0(a\sqrt{i})}{4\sqrt{i}}+\frac{J_0(a  i \sqrt{i})}{4i \sqrt{i}}\Big) 
$$
Which is not definitely $\operatorname{kei}$ function. Also, we simply put $a=2$ (remember $a$ is a positive real number) and compute the integral by wolfram alpha, we get a different [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20%28x%5E2%2F%28x%5E4%20%2B1%29%29*Besselj%5B0%2C2x%5D%20dx%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20), which is neither matched with my computations nor with the table of integrals. I appreciate any help!

Edit: As @Gonçalo points out in the comments, the integral on the curve $Re^{i \theta}$ does not vanish. So, my idea on using residue theorem was completely wrong! However, I am still seeking for an appropriate way to deal with this type of integrals and write it down as a sum of Bessel functions for instance.

Comment: @Gonçalo
Well, $\frac{x^2}{x^4+1} < \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^4-1}$ and $J_0$ is bounded by a number like $M$. Also, the length of that arc is $\pi R$. So,$\int\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}J_0(ax) dx < \frac{R^2}{R^4-1}*\pi R*M $, which in the limit $R \rightarrow \infty$ goes to zero.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks! I edited my question, too. Do you have any idea how to solve the integral then?

Comment: I tried it once and I didn't go anywhere. But I'll try it again. Thank you by the way!

Comment: @Re_Born Use $$
{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 }}{{x^4  + 1}}H_0^{(1)} (ax){\rm d}x} 
$$ instead. The [asymptotics](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E5) of the Hankel function shows that you will not encounter the issue raised by Gonçalo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's a typo in the G&R tables, and that it should be $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\color{red}{x}J_{0}(ax)}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx= -\operatorname{kei}(a) \, , \quad a >0, \tag{1}$$ where [$\operatorname{kei}(z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kei.html)$ = \Im \left( K_{0}(z e^{i \pi/4}) \right).$

We can prove $(1)$ using the approach that **Gary** mentioned in the comments.

The [Hankel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions:_H(1)%CE%B1,_H(2)%CE%B1) of the first kind of order zero is defined as $$H_{0}^{(1)}(z) = J_{0}(z) + i Y_{0}(z). $$

The principal branch of $H_{0}^{(1)}(z)$ is analytic in the right half-plane with a branch cut along the negative real axis.

Let's integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{z H_{0}^{(1)}(az)}{1+z^{4}} $$ around the quarter-circle contour $[r, R] \cup Re^{i[0, \pi/2]} \cup [iR, i r] \cup r e^{i[\pi/2, 0]}$.

Since $\lim_{z \to 0}z f(z) = 0$, the integral along the small quarter-circle about the origin vanishes  as $r \to 0$.

And since $ |f(z)| \sim O \left(\frac{e^{-a\Im(z)}}{|z|^{7/2}} \right)$ as $|z| \to \infty$ in the upper half-plane ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms)), the integral along the large quarter-circle vanishes as $R \to \infty$.

We therefore have

$$ \begin{align} \small \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xH_{0}^{(1)}(ax)}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx + \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{i \pi/2}t  \, H_{0}^{(1)}(a e^{i \pi/2}t)}{1+(e^{i \pi /2}t)^{4}} \, e^{ i \pi /2} \, \mathrm dt &=  \small \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xH_{0}^{(1)}(ax)}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx + \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{t  H_{0}^{(1)}(ae^{i \pi/2}t)}{1+t^{4}} \,  \mathrm dt \\ &=  2 \pi i  \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{z H_{0}^{(1)}(az)}{1+z^{4}}, z = e^{\pi i/4} \right] \\ &= 2 \pi i  \, \frac{e^{\pi i /4} H_{0}^{(1)}\left(a e^{ \pi i /4}\right)}{4e^{3 \pi i/4}} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2}   H_{0}^{(1)} \left(ae^{\pi i/4} \right) \\ &=\frac{\pi}{2} H_{0}^{(1)} \left(e^{i\pi/2} a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right) . \end{align} $$

For $ - \pi \le \arg(z) \le \pi/2$, the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order zero ($K_{0}(z)$) is connected to $H_{0}^{(1)}(z)$ by [the formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27#E8) $$K_{0}(z) = \frac{\pi i}{2} H_{0}^{(1)} \left(e^{i \pi/2} z \right). $$

Therefore, the integrand $\frac{t H_{0}^{(1)}(a e^{i \pi/2} t)}{1+t^{4}}$ is purely imaginary.

And equating the real parts on both sides of the above equation, we have

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x J_{0}(ax)}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx &=  \Re \left(\frac{\pi}{2} H_{0}^{(1)} \left(e^{i\pi/2}a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right) \right) \\ &= \Re \left( -i K_{0} \left(a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right) \right) \\ &= \Im  \left(K_{0} \left(a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right)  \right) \\ &= - \Im \left(K_{0} \left(a e^{\pi i/4}  \right)  \right) \tag{2} \\ &= - \operatorname{kei}(a). \end{align} $$

$(2)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle

---

Similarly, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3}J_{0}(ax)}{1+x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx &=  \Re \left(\frac{\pi i }{2}  H_{0}^{(1)} \left(e^{i\pi/2}a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right) \right) \\ &= \Re \left(K_{0} \left(a e^{- \pi i/4}  \right) \right) \\ &= \Re \left(K_{0} \left(a e^{\pi i/4}  \right) \right) \\ &= \operatorname{ker}(a) . \end{align} $$

Comment: The error is even not listed in  https://www.mathtable.com/errata/gr7_errata.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for comments*

According to Mathematica,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}J_0(ax)\, dx=\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}} (\text{ber}_0(a)+\text{bei}_0(a))-$$ $$a \,
   _1F_4\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac
   {a^4}{256}\right)$$

provided that $\Re(a)\geq 0\land
   (\Im(a)>0\lor \Re(a)>0)$,

This has been checked numerically.

For the integral given in $6.537$ in the table, assuming $a>0$ and $b>0$, for sure, Mathematica returns

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+a^4}J_0(bx)\, dx=\frac{\pi  }{2 \sqrt{2} a}(\text{ber}_0(a b)+\text{bei}_0(a b))-$$
$$b \,
   _1F_4\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{a^4 b^4}{256} \right)$$